# Can't debug react-native project from Xcode, but It's running from console

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, react-native

Operating system macOS Mojave (version 10.14.5)
React Native Project 0.59.10

I'm working on one big react-native project. When I'm running `react-native run-iso` it runs emulator, and everything is perfect.

However, if I'll go into ios directory and try to build a project from Xcode, I'm getting the error. `Library not found for -lBase64`

I've tried:

1. Install different versions of Xcode
2. Remove some system files of xCode in the system. Reinstall Xcode
3. Tried run on Emulator and Physical device (Both failed)
4. Deleted build and pod directories out of ios directory

Meanwhile, this project is building from Xcode without a problem to my Colleague computer.

When I'm running through console I see:

info Building using

`xcodebuild -workspace [name-of-the-app].xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme [name-of-the-app] -destination id=[some-long-id]  -derivedDataPath build/[name-of-the-app`

Maybe I have to define this parameter somewhere? Any solutions, any ideas?

Comment: Which file did you open on Xcode?  (.xcworkspace  or .xcodeproj )  And did you install pods? At last but not least, which version of target deployment you use?